# Issue with jquery .load() in Internet Explorer - works fine in other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, refresh

I'm having some trouble with some jQuery in IE. no errors showing up in console so it's very difficult to debug.

I'll give you the lowdown on how the script works

> Index.php
>
> > < div id='tableholder' > [article.php gets loaded into this div by a PHP include() the first time around]  < / div >

So within the article.php I have a button for refresh:
    < img id='fresh' src='whatever.jpg' />

and I also have the following code at the top of article.php:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//                           REFRESH BUTTON 
    $('#fresh').click(function() {
        $('#loadergif').show(); //show loader gif until load complete
        $("#tableholder").load('article.php?site=whatever','');
        $('#loadergif').hide(); //hide loader gif when load is complete
    });
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
});
</script>
```

So when I click on the refresh button (image) it reloads the tableholder div -and this works fine on Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox  - but on IE8 it only works once. after that it's as if the jQuery within goes dormant. I've tried adding jQuery again within the article.php but that doesn't seem to fix it either.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is your jQuery version up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.post()` instead of using `.load()`. As I have seen, `.load()` worked for me in Internet Explorer 8 though. Also you can check your jquery version once, if that is updated.

Make sure `.click()` is working properly. Can you tell the error thrown by the browser?

Comment: Thanks but as stated before there are no errors thrown in the IE console at all.

Comment: So, in that case you can use <code>.post()</code>. Will you please inform me, if you use this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I will do some seperate testing using .post() - Thanks

Comment: I was telling you to use .post()

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding but what I meant was "yes - I will do some testing using your recommendations"

Comment: Thank you - although using .post() was very helpful - it turned out that IE8 was caching my PHP page even though it's supposed to be dynamic. How I fixed it was to add the following lines to my PHP : `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Pragma: no-cache');`

Comment: one other way to stop this would be to pass a random string to the PHP so the ajax 'URL' is different every time.

Answer (score 3):

try to change `click()` with `live()` and move that script in your index.php

Probably IE8 in some circustances doesn't fire the DOMready event (inside `article.php`) when you load the content via ajax so your function is not executed

Doing so, `live()` method is necessary because if the button is within the article, `click()` method will bind a function only once at the first DOMready event.

When a page is loaded via ajax you change the `#fresh` element so you lose the previous reference to that element. `live()` will allow you to always  bind an event to the element `$('#fresh')`, also if it's re-injected later into the document

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio. This makes sense to be honest. I originally had it in the index.php but had some other issue. I would imagine live() will help me here. Will test this later and update this question.

Comment: Hmmm, as of jQuery 1.7, .live() is deprecated. Apparently I should be using .on() ??